# Segmentation fault: 11 no conversion Abort trap: 6

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, segmentation-fault

I'm new to C++11, I'm trying to use a large dataset from IMDb (working on mac, that's I hope the issue).

I'd like to implement three functions: read_graph, which reads lines from a txt file (coming from a tsv.gz file and modified with a .sh script), build_graph, which build the graph using *vector* while reading the txt files cited, and print_graph, which print the graph. The error I get (compiling on OS shell) is *Segmentation Fault: 11* or *libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion
Abort trap: 6*(but I don't exaclty how this was generated wrt the previous since I changed a little bit of the code) and I think the problem is inside build_graph, since if I remove it from the code it compiles. Any idea on what might have went wrong? Any help or advice would be appreciated, here's the code:

```
   #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    #include <queue>
    #include <list>
    #include <stack>
    #include <fstream> // getline
    #include <algorithm> // find
    #include <math.h> // ceil
    #include <sys/time.h> // gettimeofday
    
    using namespace std;
    
    constexpr int MAXN=13000000;
    vector<int> adj[MAXN];
    
    struct character{
        int id;
        string name;
    };
    
    struct movie {
        int id;
        string name;
    };
    
    vector<character> all_actors;
    vector<movie> all_movies;
    
    void read_graph()
    {
        ifstream actors_ress("act_s.txt");
        ifstream movie_s("filtered_movies.txt");
    
        string s,t;
        string del=" ";
    
        while(getline(actors_ress,s)) {
                character tmp;
                tmp.id=stoi(s.substr(0, s.find(del)));
                tmp.name=s.substr(s.find(del)+1);
                all_actors.push_back(tmp);
            }
            while(getline(movie_s,t)) {
                movie tmp;
                tmp.id=stoi(t.substr(0, t.find(del)));
                tmp.name=t.substr(t.find(del)+1);
                all_movies.push_back(tmp);
            }
        }
    
        void build_graph()
        {
            ifstream relations("connections.txt");
            string s,t,r;
    
            int u,v;
            string del=" ";
            vector<int> troupe;
    
            getline(relations,s);
            int current_movie=stoi(s.substr(0, s.find(del)));
    
            while(getline(relations,t)) {
                int next_movie=stoi(t.substr(0, t.find(del)));
    
                if(next_movie == current_movie) {
                    u=stoi(s.substr(s.find(del)+1));
                    troupe.push_back(u);
                    while((next_movie == current_movie)&&(getline(relations,r))) {
                        v=stoi(t.substr(t.find(del)+1));
                        troupe.push_back(v);
                        t=r;
                        next_movie=stoi(t.substr(0, t.find(del)));
                    }
    
                    for(auto first=troupe.begin(); first!=troupe.end(); ++first) {
                        for(auto second=first+1; second!=troupe.end(); ++second) {
                            u=*first;
                            v=*second;
                            if(find(adj[u].begin(), adj[u].end(), v) == end(adj[u])) {
                                adj[u].push_back(v);
                                adj[v].push_back(u);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                current_movie=next_movie;
                s=t;
                troupe.clear();
            }
        }
    
        void print_graph()
        {
            for(int u=1; u<MAXN; ++u) {
                if(!adj[u].empty()) {
                    cout << u << ": ";
                    for(auto v:adj[u]) {
                        cout << v << "\t";
                    }
                    cout << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    
    int main() {
    
    read_graph();
    build_graph();
    print_graph();
    }
```

Comment: The exception is telling you that what you handed as argument to `std::stoi` could not be converted to an integer. Run your code under a debugger and see what the substring you are handing it is. Then compare with what you expected to convert here. Step through the program in the debugger as necessary to determine your logic error.